# XSLT Parsing error when using Umbraco GetMedia

Tags: xslt, umbraco

I am trying to retrieve the url to an image using the GetMedia mediapicker.

The code below works fine:

```
<xsl:for-each select="umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById(1123)/* [@isDoc]">
  <article>
     <img width="1822" height="600">
       <xsl:attribute name="src">
         <xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:GetMedia(1139, 0)/umbracoFile" />
       </xsl:attribute>
     </img>
     <div class="contents">
        <h1>
          <xsl:value-of select="bannerHeading1"/>
        </h1>
      </div>
  </article>
</xsl:for-each>
```

However, if I replace the key line with this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:GetMedia(bannerImage, 0)/umbracoFile" />
```

I get a parsing error with the exception being an **OverflowException** (Value was either too large or too small for an Int32), which suggests that it's not the 1139 that is being passed in.

Is there a way I can pass in the property I want?  The value of "bannerImage" is 1139 as I want it to be?

Thanks for any help.

**Further:** This is the XML structure being returned by GetXMLNodeById:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<HomepageBanner id="1141" parentID="1123" level="3" writerID="0" creatorID="0" nodeType="1124" template="1125" sortOrder="0" createDate="2013-08-12T15:53:48" updateDate="2013-08-12T15:54:18" nodeName="Members" urlName="members" writerName="admin" creatorName="admin" path="-1,1065,1123,1141" isDoc="">
  <bannerImage>1139</bannerImage>
  <bannerHeading1>Members Area</bannerHeading1>
  <bannerHeading2>..the place for all your needs</bannerHeading2>
</HomepageBanner>
```

Comment: Please include what `umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById(1123)` returns.

Comment: I meant the actual XML structure that function call returns, pasted as XML.

Comment: Don't tell us "I get a parsing error." Tell us what the error is. You might not understand it, but that doesn't mean no-one else does.

Comment: @Tomalak, MichaelKay : I've added notes.  Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: Have you double-checked your expectations? What does `<xsl:value-of select="bannerImage" />` output when placed above the `<img>`? Apart from that, the XSLT is syntactically valid. An error would happen as a run-time error in `umbraco.library:GetMedia()`, which is why I assume you are not passing the correct arguments for that function.

Comment: @Tomalak - writing out the value of "bannerImage" outputs "1139", which is why I am confused. Thanks for validating the XSLT - I can focus down the Umbraco route now.

Comment: It *should* not make much of a difference, but you can give `umbraco.library:GetMedia(number(bannerImage), 0)/umbracoFile` a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else trying to get an image from an item in a content folder, this is how I got it to work:

```
<xsl:for-each select="umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById(1123)/* [@isDoc]">
  <article>
    <!-- Store the ID -->
    <xsl:variable name="mediaId" select="bannerImage" />
      <!-- Check the ID is numeric -->
      <xsl:if test="number($mediaId) &gt; 0">
        <xsl:variable name="mediaNode" select="umbraco.library:GetMedia($mediaId, false())" />
        <xsl:if test="string-length($mediaNode/umbracoFile) &gt; 0">
          <img src="{$mediaNode/umbracoFile}" width="1822" height="600" />
          <div class="contents">
            <h1>
              <xsl:value-of select="bannerHeading1"/>
            </h1>
          </div>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:if>
    </article>
</xsl:for-each>
```

You first need to check that the value is numeric and then, the bit that was failing me, you need to add the `"/umbracoFile"` part to your media node variable.

Thanks to the contributors who helped me in the right direction.

Comment: A few general hints: You can use `<xsl:if test="number($mediaId)">`, because `NaN` evaluates to `false` (okay this would allow values <= 0, if you expect to get those, `> 0`is of course required - but in this case you can use `$mediaId > 0` because numerical comparison coerces both arguments to number automatically). You can also use `<xsl:if test="$mediaNode/umbracoFile">` because the empty string (or empty node-set, respectively) evaluates to `false` as well.

Comment: @Tomalak - That's great thanks.  A much welcomed piece of advice for me and also others who might be new to xslt.

Comment: Since [the docs](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/umbracolibrary/getmedia) don't say anything about it, how does `GetMedia()` react when you send `NaN` as the first argument? (`umbraco.library:GetMedia(number(''), false())`)

Comment: That is also a `System.OverflowException` with "Value was either too large or too small for an Int32".